# iOS: is it possible to programmatically read the phone battery percentage?

Tags: ios, battery

Is it possible to programmatically **read** the **phone battery percentage** from an iOS App?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code.

```
if (![[UIDevice currentDevice] isBatteryMonitoringEnabled])
 {
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
 }
 NSLog(@"battery : %f", [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can you this code to check battery state and life

```
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [device setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

    int state = [device batteryState];
    // 0 - UnKnown 1 - UnPlugged 2 - Charging 3 - Full
    NSLog(@"Battery Current State : %d",state);     

    double batteryPer = (float) [device batteryLevel] * 100;
    NSLog(@"Battery Percentage Left: %ld", batteryPer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version.

```
if !(UIDevice.currentDevice.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled){
    UIDevice.currentDevice.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
}
print("Battery level: \(UIDevice.currentDevice.batteryLevel)")
```